# How to insert data JSON in JavaScript variable to datatable

Tags: javascript, json, datatable

I have data JSON result from ajax jQuery, I save in variable and then i want JSON in variable insert into datatable, but now which insert is data json from url.

I tried to change the variable value with variable result myjson, but still didn't work. This my code:

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
    var myTable = $('#my_logs').DataTable({
        "paging": true,
        "lengthChange": true,
        "searching": true,
        "ordering": true,
        "info": true,
        "autoWidth": true,
        "data": [],
        "columns": [{
            "title": "Date",
            "data": "log_time"
        }, {
            "title": "User Name",
            "data": "user_name"
        }, {
            "title": "Class",
            "data": "class_name"
        }, {
            "title": "Function",
            "data": "class_function"
        }, {
            "title": "Action",
            "data": "action_title"
        }, {
            "title": "Description",
            "data": "action_description"
        }]
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#search").click(function() {
            var start_date = $('#start_date').val();
            var end_date = $('#end_date').val();
            console.log(start_date);
            console.log(end_date);                

            if(startDate != '' && endDate !='')
            {
                var startDate = new Date(start_date);
                var endDate = new Date(end_date);
                let url = 'http://localhost/APICI/index.php/api/cektable';
                    fetch(url)
                    .then(res => res.json())
                    .then((out) => {
                        var resultProductData = out.filter(function(a) {
                            var createdAt = new Date(a.log_time);
                            if( createdAt >= startDate && createdAt <= endDate ) 
                            return a; 
                        });
                        console.log(resultProductData);
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'http://localhost/APICI/index.php/api/cektablee',
                            data: {
                                json: JSON.stringify(resultProductData)
                            },
                            type: "POST",
                            timeout: 30000,
                            dataType: "json", // "xml", "json"
                            success: function(logs) {
                                myTable.clear();
                                $.each(logs, function(index, value) {
                                    myTable.row.add(value);
                                });
                                myTable.draw();
                            },
                            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, ex) {
                                alert(textStatus + "," + ex + "," + jqXHR.responseText);
                            }
                        });
                    })
                .catch(err => { throw err });
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Both Date is Required");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want which insert to datatable is value json in variable **resultProductData** but now the result is json from **url** in ajax *http://localhost/APICI/index.php/api/cektablee*

This the result json from variable **resultProductData**
[json data result var](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-J_dIBfgF295vDCxcepje-PazhqHLQ5t)
but this the result in **datatable**
[json data result url](https://drive.google.com/open?id=17wRZr1OnuBKIuf86XqHnaaPwrX70IrY9)

Comment: Can you add the json object of logs variable in your question

Comment: [{
    "log_time": "2019-08-27",
    "user_name": "Me",
    "class_name": "login",
    "class_function": "authentication",
    "action_title": "User login",
    "action_description": "I am logged in"
}, {
    "log_time": "2019-08-17",
    "user_name": "me",
    "class_name": "dashboard",
    "class_function": "index",
    "action_title": "Admin dashboard",
    "action_description": "I am logged in"
}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you out:

tested and data is appending properly, please let me know if any query

```html
<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">


<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<html>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <table id="my_logs" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div> 
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
 
 var myTable = $('#my_logs').DataTable({
        "paging": true,
        "lengthChange": true,
        "searching": true,
        "ordering": true,
        "info": true,
        "autoWidth": true,
        "data": [],
        "columns": [{
            "title": "Date",
            "data": "log_time"
        }, {
            "title": "User Name",
            "data": "user_name"
        }, {
            "title": "Class",
            "data": "class_name"
        }, {
            "title": "Function",
            "data": "class_function"
        }, {
            "title": "Action",
            "data": "action_title"
        }, {
            "title": "Description",
            "data": "action_description"
        }]
    });
    
    var logs = [{ "log_time": "2019-08-27", "user_name": "Me", "class_name": "login", "class_function": "authentication", "action_title": "User login", "action_description": "I am logged in" }, { "log_time": "2019-08-17", "user_name": "me", "class_name": "dashboard", "class_function": "index", "action_title": "Admin dashboard", "action_description": "I am logged in" }];
    myTable.clear();
    $.each(logs, function(index, value) {
        myTable.row.add(value);
    });
    myTable.draw();

});
</script>

</html>
```